# Turn an image into lines and circles

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

I need to be able to turn a black and white image into series of lines (start, end points) and circles (start point, radius). I have a "pen width" that's constant.

(I'm working with a screen that can only work with this kind of graphics).

Problem is, I don't want to over complicate things - I could represent any image with loads of small lines, but it would take a lot of time to draw, so I basically want to "approximate" the image using those lines and circles.

I've tried several approaches (guessing lines, working area by area, etc) but none had any reasonable results without using a lot of lines and circles.

Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide example images of the input and output you want?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what language you are working in here but I'd suggest OpenCV if possible. If not, then most decent CV libraries ought to support the features that I'm about to describe here.

You don't say if the input is already composed of simple shapes ( lines and polygons) or not. Assuming that it's not, i.e. it's a photo or frame from a video for example, you'll need to do some edge extraction to find the lines that you are going to model. Use a Canny or other edge detector to convert the image into a series of lines.

I suggest that you then extract Circles as they are the richest feature that you can model directly. You should consider using a Hough Circle transform to locate circles in your edge image.  Once you've located them you need to remove them from the edge image (to avoid duplicating them in the line processing section below).

Now, for each pixel in the edge image that's 'on' you want to find the longest line segment that it's a part of. There are a number of algorithms for doing this, simplest would be Probabilistic Hough Transform (also available in openCV) to extract line segments which will give you control over the minimum length, allowed gaps etc. You may also want to examine alternatives like  [LSWMS](https://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/faster-line-segment-detection-opencv-c-source-code/) which has OpenCV source code freely available.

Once you have extracted the lines and circles you can plot them into a new image or save the coordinates for your output device.